# creating a sub module FOR loop

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

Is it possible to create this Submodule? The code works fine when all the code is in main, just not as a submodule.

```
    {
    public static void main (String [] arsg)
            {
            int  number, inWeight, weight;
            boolean veriWeight;
            weight=inWeight();

            System.out.println("Average month weight is "+(weight/12));
            System.exit(0);
            }
                   private static int inWeight ();
                   {
                   for (int i=1; i<=12; i++)
                      {
                      number=ConsoleInput.readInt("enter month weight");
                      while (number<=0)
                        {
                        System.out.println("error, try again");
                        number=ConsoleInput.readInt("enter month weight");
                        }
                        inWeight += number;
                        }
                        return number;

    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not just move a block of code inside a method. You have to be careful to pass all the variables that are needed in the code as parameters to that method, or to declare them in the body of the method itself; otherwise the code can not access them, because they are in a different "[scope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_science%29)".

In your case, all the variables are declared in your `main` method, so they are not available when they are needed in the `inWeight` method. Change your code to something like this, then it should work.

```
public static void main (String [] arsg) {
    int weight = inWeight();
    System.out.println("Average month weight is " + (weight / 12));
}

private static int inWeight() {
    int result = 0;
    for (int i=1; i<=12; i++) {
        int number = ConsoleInput.readInt("enter month weight");
        while (number <= 0) {
            System.out.println("error, try again");
            number = ConsoleInput.readInt("enter month weight");
        }
        result += number;
    }
    return result;
}
```

I've moved your `number` and `inWeight` variables to the method body, and also renamed `inWeight` to `result` to avoid confusion with the method itself. Also note that you were returning the last number entered by the user, not the total weight.